# Table "BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE" not found: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException

Tags: spring, spring-batch, h2, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I am trying to run my application using the embedded h2 db.

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ?]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME from BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE where JOB_NAME = ? and JOB_KEY = ? [42102-197]
```

I've already tried:

1. Deleting the h2 repository from the .m2 local folder and re-import and re-install - unsuccessfully.
2. I also tried configuring the properties file with the following:

> spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
>
> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
>
> spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
>
> spring.jpa.show-sql=true
>
> spring.h2.console.enabled=true

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

I had a circular dependency while I was trying to select the JOB-INSTANCE in an early stage before the embedded DB was configured.

Changing the bean instantiation order fixed it.